# How to get rid of error 422 laravel in a unit test?

Tags: testing, laravel-5

So I'm writing unit tests for a laravel 5.7 web app and when I test the login it gives me error 422(I know that it has something to do with invalid data, I just don't know how to fix it)

```
public function testRegularUserLogin_CreatedRegularUse_ReturnsStoreView()
{
    $regularUser = factory( User::class)->create();

    $response = $this->json('POST','/login',
        [
            'email' => $regularUser->email,
            'password' => $regularUser->password,
            '_token' => csrf_token()
        ]);


    $response->assertStatus(200);


}
```

I've tried using the csrf token on the header

[This is the output that test gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkDS9.png)

Comment: whats the test log output show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just mock authentication:
do something like this

```
public function getFakeClient()
{
    $client = factory(App\User::class)->create();
    $this->be($client);

    Auth::shouldReceive('user')->andReturn($this->client);
    Auth::shouldReceive('check')->andReturn(true);

    return $this->client;
}
```

then

```
$user = $this->getFakeClient();
$user->shouldReceive('posts')->once()->andReturn(array('posts'));
```

as recommended by Taylor Otwell himself [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/848#issuecomment-16006985).